# SQL statement that only fetches the newest department which has been allocated

Tags: c#, sql, database, oracle, visual-studio

In my database i have the following rows and columns: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr9q5.jpg

My problem is the same employee has 3 different departments, but he is currently only active in 1. How do I change this SQL statement to only include the latest department he is in, which started in 2018 and ends in 2100, as seen by the ALLOCATION_START and ALLOCATION_END?

**Query**

```
string agentIdSubQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT " +
                                     "AGENT_ID " +
                                 "FROM " +
                                     "KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION " +
                                 "WHERE " +
                                     "LENGTH(AGENT_INITIALS) < 5";



        if(queryParams.SnapshotDate.HasValue)
            agentIdSubQuery += " AND " + OracleConversion.ToOracleDate(queryParams.SnapshotDate) + " BETWEEN ALLOCATION_START AND ALLOCATION_END";
```

#### Update:

Tried alot of different solutions, but it crashes everytime, when i run through the debugger, further Down in this method this Query is causing me to crash:

```
 string sql = "SELECT " +
                         "age1.* " +
                     "FROM " +
                         "KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION age1 " +
                     "INNER JOIN " +
                         "(" + agentIdSubQuery + ") age2 ON age1.AGENT_ID = age2.AGENT_ID " +
                     "ORDER BY " +
                         "AGENT_INITIALS";
```

#### Error Message:

> {"Error occured during execution of SQL query: SELECT age1.* FROM KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION age1 INNER JOIN (SELECT max(DISTINCT AGENT_ID FROM KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION WHERE LENGTH(AGENT_INITIALS) < 5 AND '2018-08-15' BETWEEN ALLOCATION_START AND ALLOCATION_END AND (UPPER(AGENT_INITIALS) = 'JKKA')) age2 ON age1.AGENT_ID = age2.AGENT_ID ORDER BY AGENT_INITIALS."}

Also giving me an inner exception:

> {"ORA-00904: \"AGE2\".\"AGENT_ID\": ugyldig identifikator"}

[Debugging error screeenshot](https://imgur.com/a/9SSbp4t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order it by the newest start date (descending) and select Top 1!

```
string agentIdSubQuery =    "AGENT_ID " +
                                 "FROM " +
                                     "KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION " +
                                 "WHERE " +
                                     "LENGTH(AGENT_INITIALS) < 5 " +
                                     " AND ROWNUM = 1 " +
                                 " ORDER BY ALLOCATION_START DESC";
```

EDIT, changed Top 1 to Rownum = 1, for Oracle syntax

Comment: Is there another way? Somehow this just crashes my program. Maybe another logic?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 is MS SQL syntax, not Oracle.

Comment: `rownum` is generated before the `order by` clause is applied, so the edited version won't work either.

Comment: William Robertson is right. As of Oracle 12c we can use `FETCH FIRST ROW` for this, before that we used window functions, and before that we used `ROWNUM` on a subquery that contained an `ORDER BY` clause - which violates the SQL standard by the way, as a subquery result is always to be considered unordered.

Answer (score 1):

The table `V_AGENT_ALLOCATION` contains various departments per agent along with the dates the agent worked there. You want an agent's last department, which you get with Oracle's `KEEP LAST`. You haven't given us much information on your table, though. Let's say that the department is referenced by an `allocation_id`:

```
select
  agent_id,
  max(id_allocation) keep (dense_rank last order by allocation_start)
    as id_current_allocation
from v_agent_allocation
group by agent_id
order by agent_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message shows the final generated SQL:

> {"Error occurred during execution of SQL query: SELECT age1.* FROM KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION age1 INNER JOIN (SELECT max(DISTINCT AGENT_ID FROM KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION WHERE LENGTH(AGENT_INITIALS) < 5 AND '2018-08-15' BETWEEN ALLOCATION_START AND ALLOCATION_END AND (UPPER(AGENT_INITIALS) = 'JKKA')) age2 ON age1.AGENT_ID = age2.AGENT_ID ORDER BY AGENT_INITIALS."}

If you format that so that it's readable, you get:

```
select age1.*
from   ks_drift.v_agent_allocation age1
       inner join
           ( select max(distinct agent_id
             from   ks_drift.v_agent_allocation
             where  length(agent_initials) < 5
             and    '2018-08-15' between allocation_start and allocation_end
             and    (upper(agent_initials) = 'JKKA') ) age2
       on age1.agent_id = age2.agent_id
order by agent_initials
```

Two syntax issues should jump out:

1. There is a missing closing bracket after `max(distinct agent_id` (the `distinct` is also redundant)
2. The date literal is missing its `date` keyword - it should be `date '2018-08-15'` (or better still, a bind variable).

The brackets around `(upper(agent_initials) = 'JKKA')` are redundant but perhaps they arise from your generator logic and it's easiest to keep them.

I'm not sure how that relates to your 'newest allocated department' requirement, though. Some sample data (not a screenshot) would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the **current** department, you should compare the allocation dates with the current date.

Your query already has this `WHERE` clause, so it should work just fine for the example provided. But if you might want to specify that you need only ONE row using the `ROWNUM` special variable clause (assuming it's Oracle).

```
SELECT DISTINCT AGENT_ID
FROM KS_DRIFT.V_AGENT_ALLOCATION 
WHERE LENGTH(AGENT_INITIALS) < 5
AND ALLOCATION_START < CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE < ALLOCATION_END
AND ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: This doesn't Work as I am using an Oracle database.

Comment: Initially, you posted your question under a MySQL tag.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. Can you edit it to Work with Oracle? I see they use a OFFSET

Comment: They use ROWNUM in Oracle as far as I know. Just edited the answer.

Comment: NOW() is also an illegal identificator in Oracle.

Comment: @PokemonMaster1 yeeeah, use CURRENT_DATE.

Comment: Can you edit it into the exact Query? Should i delete the AgentIdSubQuery or how would i fit it into my code snippet

Comment: @PokemonMaster1 Sorry, I have no experience with C#. But the SQL code should be fine, so you should be able to update your C# code easily.